# Global variables and asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, global-variables

I have a problem with my  global variable `n`:

```
var n ;

socket.on('connect', function(){

socket.on('news', function  (mensaje) {

 n = mensaje.data; 
$('#string').val(n);  //  show  data

  });  

  $('#string1').val(n);    // I can't see anything, why?

 ...});
 //
```

First, my  global variable n  only  shows inside  `socket.on`  but I want it to show  out that  function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that socket.on has *not* finished (or invoked the callback) when the problematic line executes. This is because `on` is an *asynchronous* operation: it returns *immediately* and invokes the callback "later" when the data is received. The data can only be used *after* the `on` callback is run.

Here is an example of execution *order*, where 1 "runs" before 2, before 3, etc.:

```
// 1
var n;
socket.on('connect', function(){
  // 2
  socket.on('news', function  (mensaje) { // "on callback"
    // 4
    n = mensaje.data;
    // 5
    $('#string').val(n);
  });
  // 3 - note that this occurs *before* 4 & 5
  //     which run in the asynchronous callback
  //     so n has not been assigned yet
  $('#string1').val(n);
})
```

The solution is to *only* use the variable after it has been assigned, which is only guaranteed after the `on` callback runs. (Promises make it really easy to chain a bunch of dependent asynchronous operations.)